Modern integral $p$-adic Hodge theory and modularity lifting and Fontaine-Mazur
As a follow-up to a comment on this answer, I'm wondering if there are expected to be applications of the new point of view on integral $p$-adic Hodge theory, à la Bhatt-Morrow-Scholze and others, to modularity lifting and the Fontaine-Mazur conjecture. Most previous work on those topics uses Fontaine-Lafaille theory (e.g., p.42 of these notes, this more recent result, among many others), which restricts greatly the Hodge-Tate weights one can consider.
While Bhatt-Morrow-Scholze does not refer to Fontaine-Lafaille theory, it does represent a great step forward in integral $p$-adic Hodge theory (along with the more recent prismatic cohomology). Therefore, is there any hope that this new machinery would be able to generalize Fontaine-Lafaille theory to something that allows more general modularity lifting theorems?

From the arithmetic perspective, (integral) $p$-adic Hodge theory is the study of $p$-adic Galois representations. That’s why it plays a role in the proof of automorphy lifting theorems. However, Bhatt-Morrow-Scholze‘s work is geometric i.e. to study the geometry of (proper smooth) schemes over a $p$-adic field. So they are not directly related but we can construct some functors to link them and study $p$-adic Hodge theory via the interplay between the arithmetic and geometric perspectives.

On the other hand, the modern results on automorphy lifting theorems are heavily dependent on the study of the geometry of Shimura varieties, where the $p$-adic geometry plays an essential role.

I disagree with the premise of this question. You seem to suggest that integral p-adic HT did not stand still in the multiple decades between Fontaine--Laffaille and Bhatt--Scholze, and many of those advances (e.g. Breuil-Kisin modules) were motivated by & immediately applied to modularity-lifting problems.

Your two example citations are (a) a set of introductory lecture notes which deliberately uses non-cutting-edge methods for simplicity, and (b) a paper somewhat outside the mainstream of research in this area. For instance, Kisin's work on potentially semistable deformation rings – which relies on Breuil-Kisin modules to go well beyond the Fontaine--Laffaille range – has been fundamental to virtually every major advance in modularity lifting since it was written (in 2007).

(typo in first comment: "did not stand still" should be "stood still".)
